# .htaccess - Redirect for all users, except me

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, litespeed

Please help me with the htaccess. I tried to create a rule whereby a user visiting a particular web page is automatically redirected to another page on the site, but if I visit it page, this rule does not work for me (for a specific IP address).

LiteSpeed ​​installed on the server, and I think fits the rule for Apache (correct if I'm wrong, I just do not understand the server software).

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [302-Moved Temporarily redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule \.html$ /anotherPage.html [R=302,L]
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your ip and anotherPage.html is the redirection page.